# Excel macro (update date when row edited) causes 'method default of object range failed' error sometimes - how do I fix it?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the run-time error "Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed" when using the following macro in my excel document.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub
    Cells(Target.Row, "H") = Date
End Sub
```

It only happens sometimes, but when it does I cannot debug as it freezes and closes excel before reopening.

I am trying to update the date in column H when a row is edited. I found this code online and modified it to fit my situation.

Comment: You're modifying the sheet, causing the event to fire in an endless loop. Disable events: `On Error GoTo SafeExit`, `Application.EnableEvents = False`, `Cells(Target.Row, "H") = Date`, `SafeExit:`, `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

Comment: Or add `If Target.Column = 8 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: That makes sense and I can see that now, thank you both. I went with Tim Williams solution since it's simpler, though I will try the other solution if I continue getting an error.